# Minecraft Server: Protecting spawn from breaking or placing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to make it so my spawn is protected, but I don't wanna install any mods or plugins.
I read something about "spawn protection in server.properties" but it is not listed there.
Any help or a idea to protect the spawn?

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to the same directory where your "minecraft_server.exe" file is located. Open the "server.properties" file in a text editor and add or modify (if already exists) the line `spawn-protection=0`. Zero means there is no spawn protection enabled. Set another number to define the range, for example 16:

`spawn-protection=16`

Players with OP-rights still can remove blocks from the protected area. For further information about this please see [this link](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties).

Comment: Ok thank you. One other question, how do you make it so when you press a button, the command block sends you somewhere in the world, completely random.

Comment: UPDATE- Nothing happened when I put it in. I wanted it pretty large, so I set it to 12. Nothing.

Comment: @Sam did you name the file server.properties or server.properties.txt? Make sure it doesn't have the .txt ending if it does.